# Eclipse: Error occurred during initialization of VM

Tags: java, eclipse

A few days I started getting this eror message when debugging my eclipse RCP:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I used to restart my stystem if that occured which fixed it but today even a restart didn't work anymore. Can anyone please give me a hint why this is suddenly appearing.

Those are the VM arguments I'm using:

```
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5 -Xmx2048m -Xms1024m -Dosgi.locking=none -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

Comment: 2048m can be difficult for a 32 bit Java to allocate. If possible switch to a 64 bit Java (or use less memory).

Comment: Thannk you greg. From your hint I got the idea to reduce the amount of memory being allocated and it starts now again (-Xmx1024m -Xms512m).

Answer (score 4):

Try to  fix it with:

Go to Start->Control Panel->System->Advanced(tab)->Environment Variables->System Variables->New:

Variable name: _JAVA_OPTIONS

Variable value: -Xmx512M

Comment: I've been trying your advice but as far as I can see this basically just starts my application with reserving 512MB of heap space. This is less then I aleady specified in my run configuration. This didn't change the outcome

Comment: Check if any updates happened yesterday/Today which is not compatible with your system(32/64bit).because once I had updated java version and my eclipse stopped working thenI reverted/uninstalled latest java version to older one

Answer (score 1):

My issue was resolved after I reinstalled latest version of JDK.

Comment: Please don't post identical answers (neither as direct copies nor as links) to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, _tailor your answers to the question_. BTW: jdk 8 is severely outdated, current version is jdk18 :)

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. Thank you @kleopatra

Answer (score 0):

You are opening Eclipse by specifying 2GB of max memory and 1GB of min memory. And the message is telling you that there is not enough memory available to support that.

Comment: I see that but I'm wondering what I can do now. As far as I know I can't specify more then 2GB RAM ? I rememebr it having something to do being a 32Bit or 64Bit System.

Comment: IIRC in a 32bit system there is a 3GB RAM barrier https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3_GB_barrier - the question is why you need 2GB of RAM allocated for your Eclipse installation. I run mine with 1GB and it works well. But that typically differs from project, used plug-ins and environment.

Comment: I completly removed the memory hints after all now and it works fine.